# Can the intersection of two hyperplanes of $R^n$ be a line?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a problem (from a book) in which one is supposed to show that the intersection of two hyperplanes in $R^n$ either a) cut each other along a line, b) map the same hyperplane, or c) never meet at any point.

How can it be that two hyperplanes cut each other along a line in $R^n$? In the book a line in $R^n$ is defined as $x = x_0 + t(x_1 - x_0)$ where $x_0$ and $x_1$ are vectors of $R^n$. I'm only getting a result of the intersection of two hyperplanes being a plane with dimension of $n-2$.

Have I understood something fundamentally wrong here or could there be a mistake in the book? The following problem in the book asks to find an equation of a hyperplane that goes through a line $L$, where $L$ is the intersection of two given hyperplanes. I can't understand that either for the reasons explained above.

Comment: I agree that (generically) the intersection of two hyperplanes in $\Bbb R^n$ should have dimension $n-2$. Maybe double-check the book's exact definition of "cut along a line"? (and "hyperplane" as well) Can you include the exact statement of the problem (and/or the following one) in case there's a nuance you're missing that we might spot?

Comment: I can but the book is in Finnish. I tried my best to translate the problem into English. Here's the follow-up problem for it shouldn't be that difficult to understand (in theory):
<br/><br/>
Define in R^4 the equation of the hyperplane that "goes via the intersection" of the hyperplanes   p1:  x1 - 2(x2) - x3 + x4 - 1 = 0   and   p2:  -2(x1) + 3(x2) + x3 + 2(x4) + 5 = 0   and also contains the point [1, 2, -1, -3]^T.
<br/><br/>
(In Finnish: Määritä R^4:ssä sen hypertasojen p1 ja p2 leikkaussuoran s kautta kulkevan hypertason yhtälö, joka kulkee pisteen [1, 2, -1, -3]^T kautta.)

Comment: If $n > 3$, then the intersection of hyperplanes **cannot** be a line. For two subspaces $U,V$, we generally have
$$
\dim(U \cap V) = \dim(U) + \dim(V) - \dim(U + V).
$$
If $U$ and $V$ are hyperplanes, then $\dim(U) = \dim(V) = n-1$, and $\dim(U + V)$ can be either $n-1$ or $n$. In the first case, we find $\dim(U \cap V) = n-1$. In the second case, we find $\dim(U \cap V) = n-2$.

Comment: Another way to see what Ben said is using the codimension inequality $$\mathrm{codim}(U\cap V)\le\mathrm{codim}(U)+\mathrm{codim}(V)$$

Comment: @BenGrossmann It seems that in this book, a hyperplane can be an affinely shifted subspace rather than a true subspace (hence "no intersection" is also possible). But of course the greater point still stands.

Comment: @Aphamino Note that the problem in your comment describes the "intersection of the hyperplanes" but never asserts that this intersection is a line. So the problem seems to be asking to find the intersection (which will be $2$-dimensional in this case) and then find the hyperplane that contains both that intersection and the given point.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your insight. @GregMartin That's how I decided to understand the problem and what it was after. And the book actually defines x = t(x0) to be a "vector line" (a one-dimenstional vector space) and x=x0+t(x1−x0) is defined to be the general "vector" that is not a vector space. Or at least that's how I understood it.